# Use timer to change image but not working

Tags: android, timer

When i using this timer to change the image, its not working. I am trying to change the image when the timer run.I put this timer inside onCreate is that okay?

```
Timer timer = new Timer("MetronomeTimer", true);
    TimerTask tone = new TimerTask() {

        int i=0;
        @Override
        public void run() {

            img1.setImageResource(Images[i]);
            i++;

        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tone, 500, 500);
```

Comment: No, at first cannot update UI from worker thread. Instead of `Timer` use for example `Handler`, `runOnUiThread` or `AsyncTask.`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
/* do what you need to do */
changeImage();
/* and here comes the "trick" */
handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
}
};
```

`changeImage` can be something like

```
void changeImage()
{
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            img1.setImageResource(Images[i]);
            i++;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank You!
But this error appear at "handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);""Syntax error on tokens, VariableDeclarator expected instead"..

Comment: make sure you have imported the right class. see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for details about the class `android.os.Handler`